# tortoiseSVN special post-commit hook

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to create post-commit hook in tortoiseSVN. I want to copy (sync) files (or whole application) to another location. My problem is that I have a web application, and we develop it on local pcs (localhost server) but when somebody commit something new to online repository I want to copy those data (or maybe whole application) to dev subdomain folder.

Comment: and "dev subdomain folder" is...?!

Comment: @LazyBadger: Mostly agreed, but when someone hopes others will formulate an intelligible answer, he should at least try to formulate an intelligible question, and take some time to explain what he tried or at least imagined as a solution. Moreover, the OP seems to have a problem because the application is a web application, but I fail to see how that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: @JB - isn't http://stackoverflow.com/a/9710704/960558 good? And, about OP troubles: "Correctly asked question is a half on answer" - I even [can't imagine, that OP really wanted to ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't use your local TSVN postcommit-hook on **server** events - it must be or server-hook, or every developer must have and use own copy of hook
2. What is target? Local path, remote FTP|SSH?
3. Can hook be scripted on Python|Perl?
4. Why you don't use pre-made CI|Deploy tools?

Dirty draft:

- Read `svn help export`, export full WC every-time for client-side hook, сopy as you can
- Examine [Tortoise SVN / Subversion push updates to Windows 2008 Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/367560/tortoise-svn-subversion-push-updates-to-windows-2008-server) topic, I'm too lazy to repeat 
  all again